# JAVA FX Media player seek() method consumes high memory in heap, it causes application crash

Tags: javafx

I am using java-Fx media-player,  while playing video if try to seek video up to specific duration, while seeking video, Media-player thread consumes huge memory in heap. and media-player hangs out. it causes unexpected application crash.

```
timeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
        public void invalidated(Observable ov) {
            if (timeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                double timeSliderValue =timeSlider.getValue();

                            mediaPlayer.seek(duration
                                    .multiply(timeSliderValue / 100.0));
                        pb.setProgress(timeSliderValue/100);    
                    }
                };
                    }
        }
    });
```

[Screenshot of how media player grab huge memory in heap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F58pS.png)

[Memory statistic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvwoZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to this bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8101978.  Apparently, the problem is that older versions of JavaFX relied on regular heap GC / finalization to free native heap allocations, and the former can't keep up is your application / user pushes too hard.

The bug is marked as fixed in JavaFX 2.2.40, and the fix has been backported to Java 7.

Comment: I couldn't find any solution yet.